# Query to return aggregate based on two unique dimensions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate

I have the following tables that contain customer and purchase data in SQL Server 2008 R2:

**Customers**

```
CustId   Last    First    Phone
   1     Doe     John    555-5555  
   2     Smith   Sally   444-4444
   3     Smith   Greg    222-1212
```

**Order_Header**

```
OrderId  CustId  Date  
 1001       3   07/08/2011
 1002       2   07/19/2011
 1003       2   03/12/2012
 1004       1   03/14/2012
 1005       3   03/20/2012
 1006       1   04/17/2012
 1007       2   06/04/2012
 1008       1   08/04/2011
```

**Order_Lines**

```
OrderId     Sequence    Item      Type    Manufacturer   Price
 1001          1        WIDGET     C         WidgCo      12.00
 1001          2        SWITCH     C        SwitchCo     10.00
 1002          1        RADIO      A        RadSupply    30.00
 1002          2        CRT        A        CRT&More     31.00
 1002          3        NCARD      G        iNetwork      5.00
 1003          1        SENSOR     E        Sensora       7.50
 1004          1        SENSOR     D        Sensora       6.00
 1005          1        WIDGET     C         WidgInc     11.50
 1006          1        RADIO      A        RadSupply    30.00
 1006          2        SCREEN     A        ScreensInc    2.00
 1007          1        ANTENNA    G       AntennasPlus   5.50
 1008          1        SWITCH     B       SwitchOutlet   6.00
```

I'm trying to create a query that will list each customer, their contact information, and the total they've spent on each Type AND the total they've spent with each Manufacturer.  So far, I've tried a variety of different JOINS, but I can't seem to get it to work.
I'm looking to return something like this:

```
CustomerId  Last  First  Phone     TYPE  TOT_TYPE  
   1        Doe   John  555-5555    A      32.00
   1        Doe   John  555-5555    B      6.00  
   1        Doe   John  555-5555    D      6.00
```

I'm also unsure of how to incorporate the Manufacturer totals.  How can I return both datasets in the same query?

Comment: Can you clarify the result that you need?

Comment: Why do you need them to be in the same data set? They are answering two completely different questions? If it's okay to mix the types together and you'd like the TYPE column to be TYPE/MANUFACTURER then it's quite easy. If you need the types to be in columns so you can put everything for each customer in a single row then a pivot is in order.

Comment: @ErikE That's true.  I realized that it would be best that I answer two separate questions with two separate querys.  Surprisingly, my boss actually LISTENED and AGREED!  Thanks again!  It's too bad I can't choose a comment as the best answer.

Comment: @TelJanini I updated my answer (which you already selected) to include the comment. So problem solved! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need them to be in the same data set? They are answering two completely different questions, and so combining them in any way doesn't really make sense. If it's okay to mix the types together and you'd like the TYPE column to be TYPE/MANUFACTURER then it's quite easy. If you need the types to be in columns so you can put everything for each customer in a single row then a pivot is in order.

If you want a pivot, use @bluefeet's solution. Otherwise, you could consider this or Gordon's version. I think this may perform better, but testing is in order.

```
SELECT
   C.DesiredColumns,
   P.Category,
   P.Item
   P.TotalPrice
FROM
   dbo.Customers C
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
         H.CustomerId,
         V.Category,
         V.Item,
         Sum(L.Price) TotalPrice
      FROM
         dbo.Order_Header H
         INNER JOIN dbo.Order_Lines L
            ON H.OrderId = L.OrderId
         CROSS APPLY (
            VALUES
               ('Type', [Type]),
               ('Mfr', Manufacturer)
         ) V (Category, Item)
      GROUP BY
         H.CustomerId
         V.Category,
         V.Item
   ) P ON C.CustomerId = P.CustomerId
```

Answer (score 6):

It somewhat sounds like you want to [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data. This can get you the total for each `type` and then each total by `manufacturer`.  There are two ways to `PIVOT` either a static or dynamic.

Static (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8559e/1))

```
SELECT custid, last, first, phone, type,
    IsNull([AntennaPlus], 0) as [AntennaPlus],
    IsNull([CRT&More], 0) as [CRT&More],
    IsNull([iNetwork], 0) as [iNetwork],
    IsNull([RadSupply], 0) as [RadSupply],
    IsNull([ScreensInc], 0) as [ScreensInc],
    IsNull([Sensora], 0) as [Sensora],
    IsNull([SwitchCo], 0) as [SwitchCo],
    IsNull([SwitchOutlet], 0) as [SwitchOutlet],
    IsNull([WidgCo], 0) as [WidgCo],  
    IsNull([AntennaPlus], 0)+ 
    IsNull([CRT&More], 0)+ 
    IsNull([iNetwork], 0)+ 
    IsNull([RadSupply], 0)+ 
    IsNull([ScreensInc], 0)+ 
    IsNull([Sensora], 0)+ 
    IsNull([SwitchCo], 0)+ 
    IsNull([SwitchOutlet], 0)+ 
    IsNull([WidgCo], 0) Total 
from 
 (
    SELECT c.custid, c.last, c.first, c.phone,
        ol1.type, 
        ol1.manufacturer,
        ol1.price
    from customers c
    inner join Order_Header oh
        on c.custid = oh.custid
    inner join Order_Lines ol1
        on oh.orderid = ol1.orderid
 ) x
 pivot 
 (
    sum(price)
    for manufacturer in ( [AntennaPlus], [CRT&More], [iNetwork], [RadSupply], [ScreensInc], [Sensora], [SwitchCo], [SwitchOutlet], [WidgCo])
 ) p
```

Dynamic Pivot (See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8559e/2))

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsTotal AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(manufacturer)
                    from Order_Lines
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(manufacturer)+', 0) as ['+ manufacturer+ ']'
                    from Order_Lines
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsTotal = STUFF((SELECT distinct '+ IsNull(' + QUOTENAME(manufacturer)+', 0)'
                    from Order_Lines
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
      = 'SELECT custid, last, first, phone, type,' + @colsPivot + ', '+ @colsTotal+' Total from 
         (
            SELECT c.custid, c.last, c.first, c.phone,
                ol1.type, 
                ol1.manufacturer,
                ol1.price
            from customers c
            inner join Order_Header oh
                on c.custid = oh.custid
            inner join Order_Lines ol1
                on oh.orderid = ol1.orderid
         ) x
         pivot 
         (
            sum(price)
            for manufacturer in (' + @cols + ')
         ) p '
execute(@query)
```

Both should provide the same results.  The difference is that the static version you must hard-code the values that you want.  The dynamic version gets the values for the columns at run-time, so if the manufacturers change it will adjust automatically.

Comment: . . it doesn't sound at all like the question wants a pivot.  The results are in separate rows, not separate columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the user would need to clarify what they want.

Comment: The user was quite clear.  The results have the customer id repeated on three different rows.  That is not a pivot.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Did you look at the code?  They do get the results in multiple rows, one row for each type and then a total for each manufacturer.

Comment: The example given has only one column for total_price, with different rows for each type.  It seems logical that the same would apply to the other field.  To me, this is quite clear, but it is up to @TelJanni to determine what s/he really wants.

Comment: @GordonLinoff My interpretation of the question is different. The solution I provided gives them the total for each type as requested and then provides them the total for each manufacturer on one row instead of broken across multiple rows.

Comment: . . Although I'm disagreeing with your interpretation, I'm not arguing, and it is really the questioner who can resolve it. Any idea, though, why my answer keeps getting downvotes? It is very frustrating when an answer is downvoted with no explanation, especially when it provides *a* valid answer to the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know why you are being downvoted. Unfortunately a comment is not required when downvoting.

Comment: I have to say I'm kind of against the pivot because it's being performed for the sole reason of allowing two sets of right-angle data to be displayed on one "line". I suppose it's not a completely unreasonable way to do it, but what if the lists get very long? Totally out of a database context, what will a report look like that shows all these? I just worry about a huge set of columns being a very good presentation. Also, if one uses SSRS, it can dynamically pivot as well, thus saving one from having to do it in the database, thus being superior in my mind if pivoting is required.

Comment: @ErikE I can understand what you are saying with the length of the report, but it really depends on what the user wants/needs.  There are of course better ways depending on how this is being used. For example, if they wanted in a UI a total by type and then a drill down this could easily be divided into 2 separate reports. I was however, offering up a solution based on my interpretation of the question

Comment: @bluefeet Oh, I wasn't criticizing you... just "discussing". :)

Answer (score 2):

Why is this being downvoted?  It is a valid answer to the question.  The question seems to want the type and manufacturer on different rows (it doesn't say this explicitly, but it is a reasonable interpretation).  Downvoting without a comment is definitely impolite.

You need to do this with a UNION.  One hint is that your final output does not fit your question.  You have no place for the manufacturer.

```
select CustomerId, Last, First, Phone,
       Type, Manufacturer, TotPrice
from Customers C join
     ((select customerId, Type, NULL as Manufacturer, sum(Price) as TotPrice,
       from Order_Header oh join
            Order o
            on oh.OrderId = o.OrderId
       group by  customerId, Type
      ) union all
      ((select customerId, NULL as Type, Manufacturer, sum(Price) as TotPrice,
       from Order_Header oh join
            Order o
            on oh.OrderId = o.OrderId
       group by  customerId, Manufacturer
      )
     ) s
     on s.CustomerId = s.CustomerId
```

Comment: Could someone please explain why this is being downvoted?  Although there might be a syntax error, it correctly answers the question.

Comment: Possible improvement: move the `Order_Header` table out of the UNION into the outer query?